# Using local (current) time as an "if" criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am a Python beginner.
I want to know that how to use local time of my country as an `if` criteria.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now)

if 20>=now.hour>21:
     print("Playing time")
else:
     print("do whatever you want")
```

I have written this code, but it's not working on local time.

Comment: Your conditions are backwards.  You're checking if `now.hour` is less than or equal to 20 and greater than 21, which is impossible.

Comment: And even if you fix the comparison, that "range" is only one hour long, so this specific example would make more sense as a simple equality check: `if now.hour == 20`

Comment: My main question is, how to use local time as if statement..

Comment: Have you set `TZ` in your environment, to indicate your local time zone?

Answer (score 0):

Your if clause should be changed.

i asume you want to print coding time, when it is between 20 and 21.

so you have to write it like this:

```
if now.hour >= 20 and now.hour < 21:
```

what you currently have does not make sense. `20 > time > 21` is logically wrong, because 21 is always bigger than 20, so it will always be false. if you still have questions feel free to ask

Comment: But that time is not in local time of my country..what to do??

Comment: datetime.datetime.now() should give you the current local time. on your pc do you have the correct timezone setup?

Comment: No, My PC have correct time zone setup..Let me run tis code again

Answer (score 0):

Better is you can use `time` in `datetime`

As it's past 9pm in India, I have subtracted one hour to check the script

```
import datetime
from datetime import time, timedelta
now = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
now = now.time()
if time(20,0) <= now < time(21,0):
    print("Coding time")
else:
    print("do whatever you want")
```

Output:

```
Coding time
```

Without subtracting one hour

```
import datetime
from datetime import time

now = datetime.datetime.now().time()

if time(20,0) <= now < time(21,0):
    print("Coding time")
else:
    print("do whatever you want")
```

Comment: since, i am a beginner...may i know the significance of timedelta here

Comment: `timedelta` allows you to add or subtract a fixed amount of hours/minutes/days/etc to a datetime to get a new datetime.